# Vue.js call component by variable name?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

Is possible in Vue.js call component by variable name?

Components are registred:

```
import Component1 from 'component1'
import Component2 from 'component2'
import Component3 from 'component3'

...

components: {
    Component1, Component2, Component3
},
```

And i am searching for something like this:

```
created() {
    var componentName = 'Component1';
    this.components[componentName]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the components property like this:

```
this.$options.components[componentName]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a basic example on how you can use dynamic component:

link to jsFiddle to play around: [link here](https://jsfiddle.net/fr86gn3z/)

```
<div id="app">
   <component v-bind:is="currentPage">
       <!-- component changes when currentPage changes! -->
       <!-- output: Updated About -->
   </component>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    currentPage: 'home'
  },
  components: {
    home: {
      template: "<p>Home</p>"
    },
    about: {
      template: "<p>About</p>"
    },
    contact: {
      template: "<p>Contact</p>"
    }
  },
  mounted(){
   this.$options.components['about'].template = "<p>Updated About</p>"
    this.currentPage = 'about'
  }
})
```